# Grammar specification for expression in python

Tags: python, expression, documentation

I am very confused by the [language reference for expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression). The language reference specifies

`expression ::=  conditional_expression | lambda_expr`

when I interpreted expression to be much more broad than just these two possibilities. I had thought maybe they had just chosen the non-terminal  for this section but indeed, when you click on many other sections, [some of which](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) I would have not connected to lambdas or conditional expressions, also link to the same definition for expressions when you click on the hyperlink.

I am very confused by this definition as I would have expected the notion of "expression" to apply to all sections of the page and be much more general and not specifically what the language reference specifies in [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: Could you give an example of something you think should be considered "an expression", that you don't think the grammar understands to be "an expression"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel my general idea of expression [comes from C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) which specifies "An expression is a sequence of operators and their operands, that specifies a computation."

so most forms of data would be an expression and the idea of expression is much more broad. Example would be attribute access 'object.attribute' or comparison 'x < y'.

Comment: Yes, Python counts those as expressions. To determine this, you need to dig deeper into the sub-rules. Probably much deeper :) The grammar is implemented as a deep hierarchy, rather than just listing every possible symbol that could appear between identifiers, as part of how precedence/order of operations is implemented.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I had a feeling that "conditional_expression" was going to lead me on a wild goose chase that would answer my question but after just a bit of digging I was quite overwhelmed